# unpacking tuple for method argument

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14

I have a syntax problem with expanding a tuple to its content.

The working code I have:

```
class Example
{
    public:
        static void Go( int i, float f)
        {
            std::cout << "p1: " << i << std::endl;
            std::cout << "p2: " << f << std::endl;
        }

        template <typename T, size_t ... I>
            static void Do( T parm )
        {
            Go( std::get<I>( parm)...);
        }
};

int main()
{
    using X = std::tuple<int, float>;
    Example::Do<X,0,1>( std::make_tuple( 1,2.2)) ;
}
```

But I want to call the expansion with something like

```
int main()
{
    using X = std::tuple<int, float>;
    using IDX = std::std::index_sequence_for<int, float>;
    Example::Do<X,IDX>( std::make_tuple( 1,2.2)) ;
}
```

So I am searching for something like ( which can not compiled... ):

```
template <typename T, size_t ... I>
static void Do<T, std::index_sequence<I...>>(T parm)
   {
            Go( std::get<I>( parm)...);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the index sequence by value:

```
template <typename T, size_t... I>
static void Do(T parm, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    Go(std::get<I>(parm)...);
}
```

Call the method like this:

```
Example::Do(std::make_tuple(1, 2.2), 
    std::index_sequence_for<int, float>{});
```

Comment: I want to avoid construction of a real object. I think that the sequence can be formulated as a compile time constant / type. I thought I have a chance to do a template method specialization, but I struggle with the syntax...

Comment: @Klaus: an "index_sequence" is not a real object, it will get completely optimized out. It's just an "empty tag" representing a compile-time sequence of integers.

Comment: Yes, I know that the optimizer works fine. But can you give me an advice how to write a method specialization. Maybe I have to start a new question...

Comment: Hardly will someone explain how to partially specialize a function template. See [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) for further details.

Comment: @skypjack: Functions yes, but methods? I am totally confused. I start my weekend now and come back on Monday :-)

Comment: @Klaus You cannot partially specialize a methods, like you cannot partially specialize a function, and if you could, this probably not what you'd want since you'd still have to put the template parameters explicitly or pass a constructed `index_sequence`. See the second part of my answer if you want a way to call `Do` without extra args.

Comment: @Klaus As mentioned by Holt, you cannot partially specialize a method, but usually you can overload the templated method with a non templated one to reach the same goal. Anyway, as mentioned by VittorioRomeo, I wouldn't not care about and create those sequences!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `std::index_sequence` (`IDX`) is not expanding in the template parameters to what you need:

```
Example::Do<X, IDX>(std::make_tuple(1, 2.2));
```

...will not "expand" to:

```
Example::Do<X, 0, 1>(std::make_tuple(1, 2.2)); // This works
```

What you need is to let the compiler deduce the template arguments for `...I`, to do so change your static method to:

```
template <typename T, size_t ... I>
static void Do(T parm, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    Go(std::get<I>(parm)...);
}
```

And then call it with:

```
Example::Do(std::make_tuple(1, 2.2), IDX{});
```

The compiler will automatically deduce the template arguments and call `Example::Do<X, 0, 1>` as needed.

If you want to be able to call `Do` without the second arguments, you can add another layer of abstraction in `Example`:

```
class Example
{
public:
    static void Go(int i, float f) {
        std::cout << "p1: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "p2: " << f << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename Tuple>
    static void Do(Tuple &&parm) {
        _Do(std::forward<Tuple>(parm),
            std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>{}>{});
    }

private:

    template <typename Tuple, size_t... I>
    static void _Do(Tuple &&parm, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        Go(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(parm))...);
    }
};
```

Then:

```
Example::Do(std::make_tuple(1, 2.2));
```

Note that the three versions:

```
Example::Do<X, 0, 1> (std::make_tuple(1, 2.2));
Example::Do(std::make_tuple(1, 2.2), IDX{});
Example::Do(std::make_tuple(1, 2.2));
```

Will likely results in the same code after compiler optimization (on my machine with `clang++-3.7` and `-O1`, the three assembly files are strictly identical).